# BMC Remedy Integration

Tags: integration, remedy

Where can I find a list of BMC Remedy 3rd party integrations? I have found nothing on their website, and their sales department put me in touch with the customer services which wouldn't take my call because I didn't have a customer number.

My company is looking into using BMC Remedy as a customer incident system, and it would be nice if I could integrate it with some software. For example, we could have an internal development tracking system such as Jira, Redmine, MantisBT, Trak, etc. which would integrate with Remedy. Or, have Rememdy itself integrate with something like Hudson or CruiseControl.

So far, I've found nothing that seems to integrate with Remedy -- even with software packages that have a ton of integrations like Hudson and Jira. I don't really care if there are third party proprietary integrations, but I'd like to make sure they already exist and not *All you have to do is hire someone at $400 to program everything for you*. I want to make sure that there is something **now** and not be promised it can be done, then find out you really can't do it.

Comment: Please check BMC Communities (it's free to register). There is an article "Remedy AR System API and Integration Interfaces Overview":
https://communities.bmc.com/communities/docs/DOC-17512

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your definition of "integrate" is different from their version.  Their version of integration means that if a source system exposes its data, then you can configure ARS to retrieve that information and map it to classes (forms) within their system.  They have a "generic" integration system that you have to customize.  It has three broad areas:

1. If you can connect directly to a 3rd party database and see its schema, then you can perform 
   retrievals of that information.  We use Oracle today.
2. They have a java API that allows you access the ARS system for custom code (I do a lot of this).
3. Flat CSV file importation of data from a source system into ARS (after export).

I looked at their online support for the systems you mention (Jira, Redmine, MantisBT, Trak) and  do not see anything that would accomplish any of the three above without your own customizations. With the work that I've done on this system it doesn't surprise me.

I work on a project today that writes custom code doing the items above.  It is a system that is configuration/development heavy for us.  Your comment: "All you have to do is hire someone at $400 to program everything for you." is not too far off from what we have to do with the system.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Seeing how few views or responses I got, I take it that Remedy isn't all that popular for the "tech set". And, your answer pretty much jives with my suspicions: Remedy doesn't have a lot of 3rd party integrations. I was shocked that Hudson/Jenkins didn't have an integration to Remedy. Hudson/Jenkins has plugins for EVERYTHING. I was also shocked that Jira didn't integration. They have similar ones for things like Salesforce.com. In fact, I saw people at Atlassian discussing the issue a few years ago, but nothing came out of it.

Comment: Just to confirm your suspicions over a year later: Remedy does not integrate well with anything. Also, it's a terrible product based on archaic technology and is very slow to evolve. Yes, it's got SOAP now, but no REST API. I'll also note that there is a perl api (arsperl), and a Windows-only ODBC driver. The latter would be fairly nice if it worked on Linux.

Comment: @djs does it have a Rest API now. I'm a bit confused because I've seen references but nothing screams "here's the documentation". Their support people are all but useless. I'm basically looking for integration with their system and a mobile application.

Comment: @djs Why not just use Azure instead? You can write application servers in any language you want and bind it to source control. 

It integrates directly with GIT and TFS. I'm sure there are more as well. There's also so much out of the box CI and CD that you can tap into relatively quickly if you don't already have it.

Answer (score 9):

I may be a bit late to the party here, but I wanted to make this info available for anybody who happened to be searching for this answer in the future. BMC Remedy has an API in Java, which uses a native library in C, as well as bindings for Perl and other languages capable of calling native code. If you can integrate with any of those languages, you can write a custom integration program and integrate with that. As 'Gary L' mentioned, Remedy can also expose any form as a web service, which, in my experience, have simple interfaces.

Since the original question was asked, BMC have created [a doc with a wealth of information](https://communities.bmc.com/communities/docs/DOC-17512) on their Wiki. A Swedish company, RRR, has also [collected every version of the Remedy Java API](http://rrr.se/download/arapi/?bmcdn) and required native libraries on a single page. It appear that you no longer need a support ID to access these pages and download the API files.

Hopefully somebody finds this helpful!

Comment: The first link is really great !

Answer (score 2):

There is another option for Remedy integration: Web Services.

BMC Remedy makes it easy to create web services (WSDL).  It creates the SOAP and XML for you.  When you buy Remedy Incident Management module,  it includes out-of-the-box web services that will allow it to consume and/or publish web services which make it easy to integrate with other systems on the intranet or externally.  There are BMC publications which provide details on ITSM integration --- but again you will need a customer/support ID to get it from BMC's website.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no to the Web Services integration.  The Version 8 system I was working on had some web services available, and they were incomplete. So I was able to do a number of functions (mostly read-only), specifically for custom display and Change Request checking, and submission of a Change Request and a Work Order.  But many functions had no web service, and I ended up brute-forcing through the web user interface (with a customized browser control) to change dates on tasks, or make tasks. Ugly, but effective. There are mid-tier JavaScript calls that can be used, if you know the secret function name and can deal with the dynamic naming convention in play. For Remedy users who are desperate for some integration, there are ways it can be done.

Answer (score 0):

few OOTB integrations are possible with BMC Products but if you want to do it with other you have to write webservices(REST or SOAP)

Companies like IBM or cisco has made connectors for integration with Remedy.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding more detail here: 
I also do a ton of direct SQL for remedy integration.
If you're careful and know what you're doing, you can have a stored proc create legal/valid records in a remedy table. (If you do it wrong, the records won't load in the client and in older versions of the windows client can actually crash the client software.)